# Extract Powerpoint chart label to Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, charts, label, powerpoint

I need to find a way to extract chart data labels from a PowerPoint chart to Excel, as many times the PowerPoint chart given to me has it's linked data broken.

I wrote the code below, but I have no clue what to do after `For Each datapoint In chtnow.SeriesCollection(1).Points...`

```
Sub Extract_Datalabels()
'Goal: To extract datalabels of Chart's series collection and write to excel        
    Dim datapoint As Point
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim chtnow As Chart
    Dim label As DataLabel
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlworksheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlworksheet = xlWorksheets.Add
    xlApp.Visible = True

    Set chtnow = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart
    For Each datapoint In chtnow.SeriesCollection(1).Points
    'Extract data labels
        If datapoint.HasDataLabel Then

            [No clue how to write to Excel]

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That's not much of an example, but it's already got issues. Code should be tested before posting. (See [mcve])

Comment: Also, use `Option Explicit` at the top of [every] module [always].

Answer (score 0):

If everything else works ok with the code, this is an easy way to write to the first column of the `xlworksheet` in excel:

```
Dim cnt As Long
If datapoint.HasDataLabel Then
    cnt = cnt + 1
    xlworksheet.Cells(cnt, 1) = datapoint.label
End If
```

However, I am not sure that after setting `xlApp.Visible = True` you would be allowed to do something like this `Set chtnow = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart`.

Comment: There should be no problem with that, since Excel and PPT maintain their own (and separate) window collections.

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of type errors with your example, but this should get the job done for you. You will need to add a reference to the `Microsoft Excel [A Number] Object Library` in order to use the `Excel` object type and all derivatives.

All testing was done using a bar chart.

```vb
Sub Extract_Datalabels()
''Goal: To extract datalabels of Chart's series collection and write to excel
    Dim datapoint   As ChartPoint
    Dim chtnow      As Chart

    Dim xlApp       As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkbook  As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlworksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Row         As Long

    Let xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1

    Set xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    Set xlworksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Let xlApp.Visible = True
    Call VBA.DoEvents

    Set chtnow = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart
    Let Row = 1
    For Each datapoint In chtnow.SeriesCollection(1).Points
        'Extract data labels
        If datapoint.HasDataLabel Then
            Let xlworksheet.Cells(Row, 1) = datapoint.DataLabel.Text
        End If
        Let Row = Row + 1
    Next
End Sub
```